# Functions in JavaScript, what are they in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, function, methods

I learned JavaScript but I am new to Java...
how can I write something that returns the same in java?
is it using methods? and if so, how?

```
//the greeting function

var greeting = function (name) {
console.log("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};


greeting("Betty");
greeting("Harry");
greeting("Jack");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java this can be done simply like this

you create a method

```
protected void methodName(String elementName){
    System.out.println("Element Name is"+elementName);
}
```

Now, you can call methods like methodName("element1")  or methodName("element2")

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void greeting(String name)
{
    System.out.print("Great to see you," + " " + name);
}

// ...

greeting("Betty");
greeting("Harry");
greeting("Jack");
```

Comment: +1, but It will look better with println.

Comment: We typed the same thing at the same time :P *high-five!

Answer (score 0):

**Just an example:**

```
public void greeting(String name){
    System.out.println("Great to see you," + " " + name);
}

greeting("Betty");
greeting("Harry");
greeting("Jack");
```

Now go pick up a book or go Google the manual ;)